# What is the uses of using a pointer in this specific scenario?

Tags: c++

In this scenario, I have a struct Data declared.

```
struct Data {
       string first;
       string middle;
       string last;
       int age;
       };
```

According to my notes, we then create a

```
vector<Data*> list;
```

To add items to this list, we have to create a new data pointer and set attributes manually.

```
Data* variable;
variable=new Data;
list.pushback<variable>
```

I do not see the merits of using this approach. Why can't we just use this?

```
vector<Data> list;
```

To add items to this list, I create a new Data variable, then use 
`list.pushback<variable>;`

Am I right to say both approaches works?

Comment: It makes you think hard about memory management, exception safety, and how not to do things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ STL: should I store entire objects, or pointers to objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141337/c-stl-should-i-store-entire-objects-or-pointers-to-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it has to be

```
 list.push_back(variable)
```

instead of

```
list.pushback<variable>
```

The difference is that in case 1 you create a pointer to the variable, which means you only store the adress of *variable* in the list. This code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Data {
    string first;
    string middle;
    string last;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
vector<Data*> list;


Data* variable;
variable = new Data;
list.push_back(variable);

cout << list[0];
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

would only return you the address of the place in memory where variable was stored. 
So to return some value of variable you could use something like

```
vector<Data*> list;
Data* variable;
variable = new Data;
variable->setage(5);
list.push_back(variable);

cout <<  (*list[0]).getage();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Where *list[0] dereferences the pointers, that means you get the value and not the adress of it.

If you work  without pointers instead

```
vector<Data> list;


Data variable;
list.push_back(variable);
```

instead, you would store a copy of variable in the list.

So in this case you could directly address variable by something like

```
list[0].getage()
```

if you create a getage() function in the struct Data.

If you don't know how to do so, an easy( maybe not the best) way is to add

```
public:
    int getage(){
        return age;
    }
    void setage(int x){
        age = x;
    }
};
```

in your struct Data.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster.
For your case, if you were to do

```
Data variable;
// change properties here
list.push_back(variable);
```

you would first create a struct `Data` on the first line, and then you would copy the entire struct when it was pushed back into the list. Since the struct is larger than a pointer to it, doing so is simply not as computationally efficient as just pushing the struct pointer.

Comment: It wouldn't be much faster than `list.push_back(Data());`

Comment: I'd say you still need to copy Data()? Although it would just be 3 empty strings and an int at that point, so it would be pretty fast.

Comment: It would get move-assigned, and `std::string` is cheap to move.