# Class containing auto_ptr stored in vector

Tags: c++, stl

In an answer to [Is it safe to store objects of a class which has an std::auto_ptr as its member variable in std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700588/is-it-safe-to-store-objects-of-a-class-which-has-an-stdautoptr-as-its-member-v) I stated that a class that contained  an auto_ptr could be stored in a vector **provided the class had a user-defined copy constructor**.

There were several comment suggesting that this was not the case, so this question is an attempt to clear the issue up. Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Z {};

struct A {

    A( Z z ) 
        : p( new Z(z) ) {} 

    A( const A & a ) 
        : p( a.p.get() ? new Z( *a.p.get()) : 0 ) {}

    // no assigment op or dtor defined by intent

    auto_ptr <Z> p;
};

int main() {
    vector <A> av;              
    Z z;                    
    A a(z);
    av.push_back( a );      
    av.push_back( A(z) );   
    av.clear();             
}
```

Please examine the above & in your reply indicate where undefined 
behaviour in the meaning of the C++ Standard could occur for this particular class used in this particular way. I am not interested whether the class is useful, well-behaved, sortable, or how it performs under exceptions.

**Please also note that this is not  a question about the validity of creating a vector of auto_ptrs - I am well aware of the issues regarding that.**

> Thanks all for your inputs on what in
>   retrospect is probably a rather silly
>   question. I guess I focussed too much
>   on the copy ctor & forgot about
>   assignment. The lucky winner of my
>   acceptance points (and points mean
>   prizes!) is **litb** for a typically
>   exhaustive explanation (sorry
>   earwicker)

Comment: Is this a 1st of April Question? AFAIK, you are more capable, than the most of us to figure out UB :-)

Comment: I knew someone would ask this :-)  But no, I'm being serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to put the list of places together that makes the example undefined behavior.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Z {};

struct A {

    A( Z z ) 
        : p( new Z(z) ) {} 

    A( const A & a ) 
        : p( a.p.get() ? new Z( *a.p.get()) : 0 ) {}

    // no assigment op or dtor defined by intent

    auto_ptr <Z> p;
};

int main() {
    vector <A> av;  
    ...
}
```

I will examine the lines up to the one where you instantiate the vector with your type `A`. The Standard has to say

In `23.1/3`:

> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of Assignable types.

In `23.1/4` (emphasis mine):

> In Table 64, T is the type used to instantiate the container, t is a value of T, and u is a value of (*possibly const*) T.
>
> ```
> +-----------+---------------+---------------------+
> |expression |return type    |postcondition        |
> +-----------+---------------+---------------------+
> |t = u      |T&             |t is equivalent to u |
> +-----------+---------------+---------------------+
> ```
>
> Table 64

In `12.8/10`:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(const X&)
> ```
>
> if
>
> - each direct base class B of X has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const B&,
>     const volatile B& or B, and
> - for all the nonstatic data members of X that are of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type const M&, const volatile M& or M.
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(X&)
> ```

(Note the last and second last sentence)

In `17.4.3.6/1 and /2`:

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ Standard Library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template component, if the operations on the type do not implement the semantics of the applicable Requirements subclause (20.1.5, 23.1, 24.1, 26.1). Operations on such types can report a failure by throwing an exception unless otherwise specified.

Now, if you look at the specification of `auto_ptr` you will note it has a copy-assignment operator that takes a non-const `auto_ptr`. Thus, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator of your class will *also* take a non-const type as its parameter. If you read the above places carefully, you will see how it says that instantiating a vector with your type as written is undefined behavior.

Comment: But my class has an _explicitly_ declared copy constructor, so I don't see how this applies.

Comment: it does not apply to that at all. it's the copy assignment operator that is missing - not the copy constructor. i would say as defined, your copy constructor is all fine.

Comment: Neil, c++98 standard had a typo that said "copy constructor" at one particular place (and i take my quotes from c++98 - only have that). in a revisions list i read c++03 fixed that. maybe it was this that made you think of a copy constructor :) (i already fixed it a hour ago)

Answer (score 4):

Objects stored in containers are required to be "CopyConstructable" as well as "Assignable" (C++2008 23.1/3).

Your class tries to deal with the CopyConstructable requirement (though I'd argue it still doesn't meet it - I edited that argument out since it's not required and because it's arguable I suppose), but it doesn't deal with the Assignable requirement. To be Assignable (C++2008 23.1/4), the following must be true where `t` is a value of `T` and `u` is a value of (possibly `const`) `T`:

> `t = u`  returns a `T&`  and `t` is equivalent to `u`

The standard also says in a note (20.4.5/3): "`auto_ptr` does not meet the CopyConstructible and Assignable requirements for Standard Library container elements and thus instantiating a Standard Library container with an `auto_ptr` results in undefined behavior."

Since you don't declare or define an assignment operator, an implicit one will be provided that uses the `auto_ptr`'s assignment operator, which definitely makes `t` not equivalent to `u`, not to mention that it won't work at all for "`const T u`" values (which is what [Earwicker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704780/class-containing-autoptr-stored-in-vector/705153#705153) points out - I'm just pointing out the exact portion(s) of the standard).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's necessarily the case that the above code will even compile. Surely the implementor of `std::vector` is at liberty to require an assignment operator to be available, from `const A&`?

And having just tried it, it doesn't compile on Visual Studio C++ 2008 Service Pack 1:

> binary '=' : no operator found which
>   takes a right-hand operand of type
>   'const A' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

My guess is that, on the guidance of Herb Sutter, the container classes in VC++ make every effort to impose the standard requirements on their type parameters, specifically to make it hard to use `auto_ptr` with them. They may have overstepped the boundaries set by the standard of course, but I seem to remember it mandating true assignment as well as true copy construction.

It does compile in g++ 3.4.5, however.

Comment: Yes, now you remind me I remember that too - I guess that answers my question :-(

Comment: that is exactly what i told him on his answer on the other question. you have to be able to assign / copy from "const T" because the requirements state it. not because it might be useful or anything like that. +1 indeed

Answer (score 0):

Since the regular `auto_ptr` semantic could suggests that the ownership is passed during the copying, I would rather use here `boost::scoped_ptr`. Of course the assignment operator is missing.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
cout << av[ 0 ] << endl;
```

Also, conceptually, a copy should leave the item copied from unchanged. This is being violated in your implementation.

(It is quite another thing that your original code compiles fine with `g++ -pedantic ...` and Comeau but not VS2005.)

Comment: "Also, conceptually, a copy should leave the item copied from unchanged." - try telling that to auto_ptr!

Comment: My question wasn't about the usefulness of the class - obviously it is completely broken, but only about UB. But as Earwicker pointed out I think VC++ may be right for once. Interesting about Comeau though...

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: You are only looking at part of the class and a special construct that does not invoke UB. The point of my example.