# Does using std::auto_ptr data members invoke UB?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, auto-ptr

As a followup to [Class containing auto_ptr stored in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704780/class-containing-auto-ptr-stored-in-vector), I believe the unstated conclusion there is that it is OK to use classes with an `auto_ptr` member as container elements, so long as **both** copy construction and copy assignment are user-defined (so as not to invoke the `auto_ptr`s copy constructor and copy assignment).  Is there **anything** about this that violates the Standard Library requirements?

Please tell me if there is anything wrong with the following, as I'd like to start doing it idiomatically:

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Y { /* ... */ };
class Z : public Y { /* ... */ };

class X {
    public:
        X() : ap(new Z()) {}
        X(const X& other) : ap(other.ap->clone()) {}
        X& operator=(X other) { swap(other); return *this; } // any problem with swap?
        void swap(X& other) { std::swap(ap, other.ap); }
        // note no destructor necessary
    private:
        std::auto_ptr<Y> ap; // Y provides clone()
};
```

Note that one thing I've realized is that with this approach, `Y`'s class definition must be in scope for `X`'s definition (as opposed to just forward-declared when a "raw" pointer to `Y` is used).  This is because when the `auto_ptr` is instantiated, its destructor must call delete on a `Y`, and so `Y` cannot be an incomplete type.  I suppose this has to be weighed against the value of RAII in the case that class `X` managed several resources (has several `auto_ptr` members).  Any thoughts on this?

I think this technique is great overall, to eliminate a lot of tricky code for classes that may have to construct/destruct/copy potentially several resources (single responsibility principal).  I'm just wondering if `auto_ptr` serves the purpose, or if it doesn't work here because of some subtle language/Standard Library requirement.

Please note that I'm aware of other types of smart pointers, but I'm implementing a library interface, and I don't want to impose any requirements for Boost or TR1 on my clients.  Any lecture on the use of `auto_ptr` in general will be downvoted!

Comment: You're calling std::swap with only one argument there. And secondly, I think your code would cause infinite recursion because std::swap uses the assignment operator.

Comment: @Timo: That's not calling `std::swap()`, but `this->swap()`. @Tabber33: The `std::` prefix for calling `std::swap()` isn't necessary, since ADL will find it when using `std::auto_ptr` as an argument. Also, the common idiom is to be `using std::swap` and then call `swap` unqualified, in order to pick up any overloads for user-defined types. (Which aren't allowed to reside in `std`, since you must not add anything to `std`, except for full specializations.)

Comment: @sbi -- I knew that, but since it's irrelevant to my question, I didn't show the idiomatic usage.  My question is about the idiomatic usage of auto_ptr as a data member.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using auto_ptr when the destructor is out of scope *does* cause undefined behavior. MSVC warns about it. GCC doesn't.

You can make it work, but only if the destructor is not defined as an inline function.

The unique_ptr and scoped_ptr fix this problem. At least with those you are prevented from writing undefined code by accident.

Comment: Why can't the destructor be defined inline?  In my case `Y`'s destructor is `virtual` and its definition is in scope when the `auto_ptr` is instantiated.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: @Zan -- can you explain how example 4(b) here: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm works? -- he explicitly states we don't need to declare/define a destructor.

Comment: Are you sure there are rather not problems when the stored type is incomplete?

Comment: @UncleBens: That is what I meant by out of scope: an incomplete type. I may not have been clear.

Comment: @Tabber33: Read this http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31875527/autoptr-compile-error.aspx and scroll down to Tamas Demjen. He gives a code example showing the problem.

Comment: @Zan: thanks very much -- great link.  I think I understand all of this now.  The bottom line is: by 17.4.3.6/2, using an incomplete type in **any** Standard Library template is UB -- end of story.

Comment: @Zan: In my case, `Y`'s definition is in scope for `X`'s definition, so `Y` is complete and there is no issue, even though `X` doesn't have an explicitly-declared destructor, correct?  Any time the compiler has to generate an implicit inline destructor for `X`, `Y`'s definition is available at that point.  I'm convinced that as long as `Y` is complete, this usage of `auto_ptr` is fine.  However, it technically violates the standard when `Y` is only forward declared, and hence cannot be used for PIMPL, even with the non-inline destructor "trick"...  accepted your answer for the link, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've implemented a ***cloning smart pointer*** on top of `std::auto_ptr`. I'm not sure this is worth the hassle, as you're not very far from implementing one on top of a dumb pointer.

But as far as I see there's no error in this. (Of course, saying so will make someone point out an obvious flaw 5mins after I post this...)

Answer (score -1):

What are you really trying to do?
Seems like alot of unnecessary work if you just want to have a bunch of objects in a container.  creating a temp object and having the object in the container take over ownership isn't a problem in my thinking

`operator =()` does not make sense to me, it is not = it is swap.

```
X a,b;
a=b
assert(a==b) // fail!
```

Your realisation is incorrect

> Note that one thing I've realized is
>   that with this approach, Y's class
>   definition must be in scope for X's
>   definition (as opposed to just
>   forward-declared when a "raw" pointer
>   to Y is used). This is because when
>   the auto_ptr is instantiated, its
>   destructor must call delete on a Y,
>   and so Y cannot be an incomplete type.

if you define the destructor for X and implement in a CPP file you can quite legally do

header

```
class Y;
class X{
  virtual ~X();
  std::auto_ptr<Y> ap; 
};
```

body

```
class Y{};
~X(){}
```

Comment: With regards to `operator=` -- it is called the copy-and-swap idiom -- look it up.  The swap is done with the temporary that gets copy-constructed for the pass-by-value parameter, not with the actual RHS object.  Will try your trick to allow a forward-declaration of `Y`, but I'm thinking `Y`'s def must be in scope at the point of `auto_ptr`'s instantiation (which is `X`'s definition).

Comment: Ok, it works.  But is it legal?  Doesn't a type have to be complete at the point of a template instantiation using that type?

Comment: Ah, I missed the lack of reference& making it copy(clone)&swap and not just swap.

Comment: Yes it is legal, template instantiation happens when it gets used. Usage for the ~auto_ptr and therfore ~Y is in ~X

Comment: No, class template instantiation happens in the class definition for `X`.  At that point, `Y` is incomplete, and this is not allowed by the standard (though it usually works from what I gather).

Comment: @tabber33: So, where is the definition? The Declaration of X is in the header. The usage of the template destructor of auto_ptr is in ~X, the definition of ~X is in the body, in the body Y is defined.  I'm just repeating myself. As far as I read we agree, but you say no.

Comment: The _definition_ of `X` is in the header.  The compiler must instantiate the `auto_ptr` specialization as part of the definition of `X`.  The size of `X` depends on the instantiated `auto_ptr`.  At this point, `Y` is incomplete, and we have UB according to the standard.

Comment: Sure, your definition of X is in the header.  Mine was not, I only declared in the header and defined in the body. Which is what Zan your accepted answer says.  Your realisation is still incorrect.

Comment: You need to understand what a **class definition** is -- look it up please.