# Is it safe to return vector<auto_ptr<T>>?

Tags: c++, vector, auto-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it wrong to use std::auto_ptr<> with standard containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers)

I have a function to return some Object in pointer, so I use:

```
vector <auto_ptr <Object> > func() { ... }
```

I want to know whether it is safe or not?

Comment: Better use c++11 smart pointers.

Comment: This is not a good idea - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2643757/160206).

Comment: You should use std::unique_ptr. Use boost's one if you can't use C++11.

Comment: It is not safe to use `vector`s of `auto_ptr`, so returning one cannot be safe either. See [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm).

Comment: See [Why is it wrong to use std::auto_ptr with standard containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

stl likes to copy elements around and use temporary copies in its algorithms (e.i. they have to be "copy-constructible" and "assignable"). While this is not true for `auto_ptr`. Assigning one `auto_ptr` to another transfers ownership of the pointer.

`auto_ptr<foo> A = B;` B becomes `NULL`, A is the new owner of the pointer and B is unusable. And when the temporary object takes ownership it does not return it and you have vector of dangling pointer or `NULL` pointers instead.

You can use c++11 smart pointer, or boost smart pointers or implement one yourself.