# Is there a general smart pointer like auto_ptr and shared_ptr that doesn't need C++0x?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm wanting a non-reference counted smart pointer that can combine some of the useful aspects of `auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.  I think that C++0x's `unique_ptr` is ultimately what I'd need, but I need something that will compile on Visual Studio 2008 and Xcode (gcc 4.2).

The functionality I need is:

- Usable in factory methods so that ownership is transferred on copying (like auto_ptr)
- Supports `release()` (like auto_ptr)
- Can be used with forward declaration (like shared_ptr)

So, I suppose it's really a better `auto_ptr`.  Is there anything that does this in boost or elsewhere (note: I haven't got the time to wrap my head around Loki)?  Or should I just roll my own?

EDIT: I've just been reading more about `auto_ptr` -- it sounds like you *can* use it with forward declarations if you ensure that the class header is included in each .cpp file that references the header with the smart pointer (eg see [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm)).  Anyone got any general advice or rules of thumb on this?

EDIT2: The reason shared_ptr isn't acceptable is because I need a release()  method as I'm tidying up some legacy code by introducing factory methods, but it has to co-exist with some manual pointer ownership code. Using shared_ptr throughout the codebase would be great, but a huge task.

EDIT3: In the end, `auto_ptr` was adequate for the job once I discovered the quirks of the forward inclusion.  It would be interesting also to try writing a custom deleter for `shared_ptr` to allow for optional deletion of the pointer.

Comment: This is exactly what I use auto_ptr for. Until I started using boost (or in situations where I can't use boost).

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/codenrun/auto_ptr_custom. It adds a custom deleter to a auto_ptr like interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: In my original answer, I failed to understand that `boost::shared_ptr` is not acceptable to you (probably for performance reasons).

`auto_ptr` does, as you note, support forward declaration. You need to include the header for the referenced class in those places that may destroy the object referenced by the `auto_ptr`. Note, however, that the semantics of `auto_ptr` are slightly quirky and require some care.

The answers to the following question contain more information, including the reason why `unique_ptr` can only be implemented for C++0x because it requires rvalue references:

[unique_ptr boost equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953530/unique-ptr-boost-equivalent)

Comment: The reason `shared_ptr` isn't acceptable is because I need a `release()` method as I'm tidying up some legacy code by introducing factory methods, but it has to co-exist with some manual pointer ownership code.  Using `shared_ptr` throughout the codebase would be great, but a huge task.

Comment: @the_mandrill: I don't see how that's a problem. Boost allows for custom deleters. You can write a custom deleter that's a no-op for pointers that you've released.

Comment: If you write a no-op custom deleter then doesn't that prevent it from ever releasing the pointer?  Or do you mean a custom deleter where you can toggle it to delete/not delete at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

**C++ TR1** (supported by modern GCC and Visual Studio) has built-in `shared_ptr` [and others (cf. Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Smart_pointers). Those have mostly been taken from **Boost** which works for pretty much any modern compiler.

If you need strict ownership, you may check the [`scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm).

Comment: both not a viable option according to the_mandrill. shared_ptr uses ref counting and scoped_ptr doesn't support release.

Answer (score 2):

With some boilerplate code you can [approximate](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html) `unique_ptr` in C++03. It's not a perfect emulation. You will need a couple more explicit `move` calls, for example, to be able to return a local `unique_ptr`.