# What is unique_ptr replacement for "visual studio 2008", no 3-rd libraries (eg. boost)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unique-ptr

Is there something like unique_ptr<> in Visual Studio 2008?

Event Visual Studio only header is also OK.

I want this feature but do not want to use 3-rd party lib. Since I am writing sample/learning code.

If not, I will have to use raw pointer directly, for simplification. Although I feel uncomfortable....

Comment: Why don't you get VS2012 and use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: You could always look at how Boost does it, or how it's done in the standard library for some compiler, and implement it yourself.

Comment: Does VS2008 have C++11 rvalue references? You would need them to "emulate" unique_ptr

Comment: you don't need boosts "library" to include it either. it is a header only file.

Comment: Finally, I just use raw pointer in my sample/learning code. It keeps simple, although I don't like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2008 does not support rvalue references and thus no move operations. `unique_ptr` behavior relies on those, so there *can* be no exact replacement in C++03. `auto_ptr` uses the copy-Ctor to do what should be done by the move-Ctor. You could use those, but I'd recommend against it, because the compiler can't help you find unwanted copies like he does with `unique_ptr`.

Also see here: [unique_ptr boost equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953530/unique-ptr-boost-equivalent)

Comment: Thank you. I knew auto_ptr, it is really bad.