# Using a unique_ptr without C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, raii

I would like to pass pointers to `d` around from one container to a next.  At no point will there be more than one owner of the pointer (or `d` itself).  I'd like that when the last pointer goes out of scope, `delete d` automatically called.

In C++11, I'd do this with unique_ptr.  But, alas, I can't use C++11.  What is the best equivalent in C++? Boost is fine.  Or, if there is none, what is the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: " I'd like that when the last pointer goes out of scope, delete d automatically called." That doesn't sound like  `unique_ptr`'s functionality, but more like `shared_ptr`'s.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is also new in C++11.  So either way, if you don't have a C++11 compiler, you have to use Boost or similar third-party library, or write your own smart pointers.

Comment: `uinque_ptr` is very similar to `shared_ptr`, except it assumes a single owner, so the pointer is moved around instead of being copied.

Comment: Take care to look at this answer updated for newer releases of Boost: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28193068/4213662

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [`boost::movelib::unique_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/move/reference.html#header.boost.move.unique_ptr_hpp) is part of the [Boost.Move library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/move.html) which offers "Portable move semantics for C++03 and C++11 compilers". Since `unique_ptr` clearly needs move semantic, this looks like your best choice.