# C++03 smart pointer with free()

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, c++03

I have a char pointer that I need to transfer ownership of, and I would rather not have to handle its lifecycle  myself if possible. The memory is allocated using malloc (no choice here).

As such I'm looking for something like C++11's [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which manages ownership and allows a custom `Deleter` to be provided.

As the title suggests, I don't have access to C++11 features though. `auto_ptr` isn't a goer as far as I'm aware, as it calls `delete` rather than `free`.

Is there an appropriate smart pointer in this case, or will I have to manage the freeing of the memory myself?

Comment: I guess you could write your own (it's not that much code)

Comment: @UnholySheep yep, I'd rather not if there is a suitable alternative out there already though

Comment: You might want to read [this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2953530/440558). Also, considering your requirements it should not be that much work to write your own custom wrapper class for this specific problem.

Comment: Depending on how intelligent the smart pointer needs to be, you could write a struct that accepts your `char*` in a ctor, and then in the destructor, calls free. This would be a lightweight unique pointer. (Of course you'd have to declare copy ctor and copy assignment as private and then not implement them to avoid copying). Ofc you'd also have to replicate the move functionality, probably as a member function that produces the `char*` pointer, and then will ensure no `free` is called in the `dtor`

Comment: I guess using [Boost smart pointers with a deleter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#deleter_constructor) might also be an option? (Though that requires you to add boost as a dependency which you may or may not want to do)

Comment: You can use `boost::shared_ptr`. Or you can write your own.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to writing it yourself you can introduce a dependency on Boost and just use `boost::shared_ptr`.

But for comparison, here’s minimal off-the-cuff C++11 and later code for an `malloc`/`free` based ownership transfer pointer, like `std::unique`:

```
template< class Type >
class My_ptr
{
private:
    Type* p_;

    My_ptr( My_ptr const& ) = delete;
    operator=( My_ptr const& ) -> My_ptr& = delete;

public:
    auto operator->() const
        -> Type*
    { return p; }

    auto operator*() const
        -> Type&
    { return *p; }

    ~My_ptr() { free( p_ ); }

    My_ptr( Type* p )
        : p_( p )
    {}

    My_ptr( My_ptr&& other )
        : p_( other.p_ )
    { other.p_ = nullptr; }
};
```

As you can see it's not much code in C++11.

Disclaimer: the above code has not been seen by compiler.

---

In C++03 the main problem is how to make it possible to return the smart pointer from a function, *without* allowing general copy construction, which would wreak havoc.

The solution used by `std::auto_ptr` was to involve a mediator pointer carrier class with implicit conversions. This was complex. I remember encountering a great number of idiosyncrasies in Visual C++'s implementation of `std::auto_ptr`, when I wrote a (once referenced by Wikipedia) pointer tutorial.

The code below, hopefully valid C++03 (tested with `g++ -std=c++03`), is instead based on the programmer explicitly indicating where a move operation is desired, by calling the `as_movable` member function. It uses `volatile` as a kind of tag, to ensure that only the moving constructor can fit when the result of `as_movable` is used as a constructor argument. The idea of using `volatile` as a tag in C++03, though in a quite different context, was once introdued by Andrei Alexandrescu; possibly by others before him, but as far as I recall his usage was where I first encountered that idea.

The placement allocation and deallocation operators, `operator new` and `operator delete`, are defined for **exception safety**. In particular, the placement `operator delete` defined here is *only* called implicitly, by a `new`-expression, when the relevant type's constructor indicates failure by throwing an exception. Then the memory is deallocated, using this operator, before the exception is re-thrown.

```
#include <exception>    // std::terminate
#include <new>          // std::bad_alloc
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>     // malloc, free, NULL

#define MY_NEW( type, args ) \
    ::new type args

#define MY_MALLOC( type, args ) \
    ::new( my::c_memory_management ) type args

namespace my {
    struct C_memory_management {};
    C_memory_management const c_memory_management = C_memory_management();
}  // namespace my

void*
    operator new( size_t const size, my::C_memory_management )
{
    void* result = malloc( size );
    if( not result ) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    return result;
}

// This operator is (only) called automatically by a new-expression where the
// constructor for the type, throws. After the call the exception is re-thrown.
void operator delete( void* const p, my::C_memory_management )
{
    free( p );
}

#ifdef SUPPORT_ARRAYS
    void*
        operator new[]( size_t const size, my::C_memory_management const cmm )
    {
        return operator new( size, cmm );
    }

    void operator delete[]( void* const p, my::C_memory_management const cmm )
    {
        operator delete( p, cmm );
    }
#endif

namespace my {
    template< class Referent >
    struct Destruction_via_delete_
    {
        static void destroy( Referent const* p )
        {
            try
            {
                delete p;
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                std::terminate();
            }
        }
    };

    template< class Referent >
    struct Destruction_via_free_
    {
        static void destroy( Referent const* p )
        {
            try
            {
                p->~Referent();
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                std::terminate();
            }
            ::free( const_cast<Referent*>( p ) );
        }
    };

    template< class Referent >
    class Auto_ptr_
    {
    public:
        typedef void Destruction_func( Referent const* );

    private:
        Auto_ptr_& operator=( Auto_ptr_ const& );   // No copy assignment.
        Auto_ptr_( Auto_ptr_ const& );              // No COPYING via copy constructor.
        // A non-const argument copy constructor, for moving, is defined below.

        Referent*           p_;
        Destruction_func*   destroy_func_;

        static void dummy_destroy_func( Referent const* ) {}

    public:
        Auto_ptr_ volatile&
            as_movable()
        { return const_cast<Auto_ptr_ volatile&>( *this ); }

        Referent*
            release()
        {
            Referent* result = p_;
            p_ = NULL;
            return p_;
        }

        Referent*
            operator->() const
        { return p_; }

        Referent&
            operator*() const
        { return *p_; }

        ~Auto_ptr_()
        { destroy_func_( p_ ); }

        Auto_ptr_()
            : p_( NULL )
            , destroy_func_( &dummy_destroy_func )
        {}

        explicit Auto_ptr_(
            Referent* const             p,
            Destruction_func* const     destroy_func    = &Destruction_via_delete_<Referent>::destroy
            )
            : p_( p )
            , destroy_func_( destroy_func )
        {}

        explicit Auto_ptr_(
            C_memory_management,        // tag
            Referent* const             p
            )
            : p_( p )
            , destroy_func_( &Destruction_via_free_<Referent>::destroy )
        {}

        // A C++03 emulation of move constructor; allows return of lvalue.
        Auto_ptr_( Auto_ptr_ volatile& other )
            : p_( other.p_ )
            , destroy_func_( other.destroy_func_ )
        {
            other.p_ = NULL;
            other.destroy_func_ = &dummy_destroy_func;
        }
    };

}  // namespace my

#include <stdio.h>

struct Blah
{
    char const* hello() const { return "Hello from Blah-land! :)"; }

    ~Blah() { printf( "<destroy>\n" ); }
    Blah() { printf( "<init>\n" ); }
};

my::Auto_ptr_< Blah >
    foo()
{
    using namespace my;
    Auto_ptr_< Blah  > p( c_memory_management, MY_MALLOC( Blah,() ) );
    return p.as_movable();
}

void bar( my::Auto_ptr_<Blah> const p )
{
    printf( "%s\n", p->hello() );
}

int main()
{
    my::Auto_ptr_<Blah> p = foo().as_movable();

    printf( "Calling bar()...\n" );
    bar( p.as_movable() );
    printf( "Returned from bar().\n" );
}
```

Output:

```
<init>
Calling bar()...
Hello from Blah-land! :)
<destroy>
Returned from bar().
```

Disclaimer: I've not written any unit test for the above code, indeed the only testing is what's shown above, that that works. Testing the various cases that one wants this to work for is IMHO necessary for use of this in a production code.

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` was my first thought too.

Comment: Pretty much no. The `auto` returns have to be substituted by proper return types, the `&&` move constructor by a move-emulation layer if so desired, and the `= delete`'s by proper private non-implemented member functions.

Comment: Deleting the answer because a single ownership pointer isn't easy to do properly for C++03. E.g. the old C++03 `auto_ptr` behaved in erratic unpredictable ways with Visual C++. **Unable to delete because it's accepted. ☹**

Comment: Given that the OP asked for a C++03 solution, accepting a C++11 (and later) answer seems a bit odd.

Comment: I guess I will have to do the C++03 thing then and amend the answer.

Comment: Good to see that this got fixed with actual C++03 code - and one that works and is sensible at that.