# Is it safe to push_back 'dynamically allocated object' to vector?

Tags: c++, vector, exception-safe

Whenever I need to add dynamically allocated object into a vector I've been doing that the following way:

```
class Foo { ... };

vector<Foo*> v;

v.push_back(new Foo);

// do stuff with Foo in v

// delete all Foo in v
```

It just worked and many others seem to do the same thing.

Today, I learned vector::push_back can throw an exception. That means the code above is not exception safe. :-( So I came up with a solution:

```
class Foo { ... };

vector<Foo*> v;
auto_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo);

v.push_back(p.get());
p.release();

// do stuff with Foo in v

// delete all Foo in v
```

But the problem is that the new way is verbose, tedious, and I see nobody's doing it. (At least not around me...)

Should I go with the new way?
Or, can I just stick with the old way?
Or, is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Please also see: [Why is it wrong to use std::auto_ptr<> with STL containers?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-stl-containers

Comment: @Martin: actually there is no issue with the use of `auto_ptr` and `vector` here (I mean, specific to their interaction), since it is not a `vector<auto_ptr<T>>` that we are talking about.

Comment: @Matthieu: You're right. Then again I avoided *saying* there is an issue, although my link probably did imply it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you care about is exception-safety of this operation:

```
v.reserve(v.size()+1);  // reserve can throw, but that doesn't matter
v.push_back(new Foo);   // new can throw, that doesn't matter either.
```

The issue of a vector having responsibility for freeing the objects pointed to by its contents is a separate thing, I'm sure you'll get plenty of advice about that ;-)

Edit: hmm, I was going to quote the standard, but I actually can't find the necessary guarantee. What I'm looking for is that `push_back` will not throw unless either (a) it has to reallocate (which we know it won't because of the capacity), or (b) a constructor of T throws (which we know it won't since T is a pointer type). Sounds reasonable, but reasonable != guaranteed.

So, unless there's a beneficial answer over on this question:

[Is std::vector::push_back permitted to throw for any reason other than failed reallocation or construction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186431/is-stdvectorpush-back-permitted-to-throw-for-any-reason-other-than-failed-rea/4186512)

this code depends on the implementation not doing anything too "imaginative". Failing that, your solution from the question can be templated up:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
void push_back_new(Container &c) {
    auto_ptr<T> p(new T);
    c.push_back(p.get());
    p.release();
}
```

Usage then isn't too tedious:

```
struct Bar : Foo { };

vector<Foo*> v;
push_back_new<Foo>(v);
push_back_new<Bar>(v);
```

If it's really a factory function rather than `new` then you could modify the template accordingly. Passing a lot of different parameter lists in different situations would be difficult, though.

Comment: Yes, for this question, all I care about was exception-safety. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Your new way is *more* exception safe but there is a reason that you don't see it done anywhere else.

A `vector` of pointers only owns the pointers, it doesn't express ownership of the pointed-to objects. You are effectively releasing ownership to an object that doesn't "want" ownership.

Most people will use a `vector` of `shared_ptr` to express the ownership correctly or use something like `boost::ptr_vector`. Either of these mean that you don't have to explicitly `delete` the objects whose pointers you are storing which is error prone and potentially exception 'dangerous' at other points in the program.

**Edit:** You still have to be very careful with insertion into `ptr_vector`. Unfortunately, `push_back` taking a raw pointer provides the strong guarantee which means that either insertion succeeds or (effectively) *nothing* happens, so the object passed in is neither taken over nor destroyed. The version taking a smart pointer by value is defined as calling `.release()` before calling the strongly guaranteed version which effectively means that it can leak.

Using a `vector` of `shared_ptr` together with `make_shared` is much easier to use correctly.

Comment: "defined as calling .release() before calling the strongly guaranteed version" - this is an outrage. Isn't it?

Comment: @Steve: Agreed. It would make more sense (to me) to take an `auto_ptr` by non-`const` reference and only `release` once ownership had successfully been transferred.

Comment: Sounds good, same as the `shared_ptr(auto_ptr)` constructor. For this usage, I'd also settle for taking it by value and either releasing or destroying, equivalent to the `shared_ptr(T*)` constructor but applied to the pointer contents of an auto_ptr parameter.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, it's most important not to leak. But if allocation failed, giving you the option to do something with the object that you failed to 'give away' is probably irrelevant for most programs as they'll rapidly be entering their "all bets off" state.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way to do this is to use a container of smart pointers, for example, a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >` or a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo> >` (`shared_ptr` can be found in Boost and C++ TR1 as well; `std::unique_ptr` is effectively restricted to C++0x).

Another option is to use a container that owns dynamic objects, like those containers provided by the Boost Pointer Containers library.

Answer (score 0):

How resilient to memory shortage is your program?  If you really care about this you have to be prepared for `new` to throw as well.  If you aren't going to handle that, I would not worry about jumping through the `push_back` hoops.

In the general case, if you run out of memory, the program already has likely insurmountable problems unless it's specifically designed to run forever in a constrained footprint (embedded systems) - in that case you do have to care about all of these cases.

If that applies to you, you could have a lengthy code review and retest cycle ahead of you.  My guess is that you are OK to follow your team's practice here, though.

As others have pointed out, using `vector` to store raw pointers has its own problems, and there is a wealth of material on this site and in the other answers to direct you to a safer pattern.

Comment: @Chubsdad - the question is tagged 'exception-safe', so I think this is relevant.  The suggested fixes all speak to raw pointer usage in `vector` without addressing what happens if `new` throws.

Comment: If the `new Foo` throws, no memory got allocated. If the `vector` reallocation throws, we just lost the address of the memory allocated by `new Foo`. And a vector reallocation can fail without being "short" in memory, if it grows too much or you memory is too fragmented.

Comment: @Matthieu - I know what happens. I just wanted to address the broader question of memory-related exception safety in ALL circumstances rather than the few lines of code posted here. I think we are agreed it's not easy.