# Is std::vector::push_back permitted to throw for any reason other than failed reallocation or construction?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance

Consider:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(1);
v.push_back(1); // is this statement guaranteed not to throw?
```

I've chosen `int` because it has no constructors that could throw - obviously if some copy constructor of T throws, then that exception escapes `vector<T>::push_back`.

This question applies as much to `insert` as `push_back`, but it was inspired by [Is it safe to push_back 'dynamically allocated object' to vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185350/is-it-safe-to-push-back-dynamically-allocated-object-to-vector/4185460), which happens to ask about `push_back`.

In the C++03 and C++0x standard/FCD, the descriptions of `vector::insert` say that if no reallocation happens, iterators/references before the insertion point remain valid. They *don't* say that if no reallocation happens, no exception is thrown (unless from constructors etc of T).

Is there anything elsewhere in the standard to guarantee this?

I don't expect `push_back` to do anything that could throw in this case. The GNU implementation doesn't. The question is whether the standard forbids it.

As a follow-up, can anyone think of a reason why any implementation would throw? The best I can think of, is that if a call to `reserve` ends up increasing the capacity to a value in excess of `max_size()`, then `insert` perhaps is permitted to throw `length_error` when the max size would be exceeded. It would be useless to increase capacity beyond `max_size()`, but I don't immediately see anything forbidding that, either [Edit: your allocator would probably stop you increasing capacity beyond `max_size`, so this suggestion might be no good.]

Comment: Excluding copy constructors that might throw during push_back?

Comment: @awoodland:  Steve is specifically using `int`s to take that off the table

Comment: @awoodland: yes, and as John says I've picked a specific example which ignores all that, for simplicity.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: RE your last paragraph, `reserve` is defined to throw `length_error` if it would exceed `max_size()` (this is independent of anything the allocator may throw).

Comment: @Steve M: I refer to the "pedantic" tag ;-) `reserve` is defined to throw if the *argument* exceeds `max_size()`, but capacity afterwards can be greater than the argument. So this odd situation, if legal, wouldn't cause `push_back` to throw in my `int` example, or in any example where you had passed a big enough value to `reserve`, but might permit it to throw in odd situations where `capacity()` is greater than `size()`, and hence the vector is not permitted to reallocate.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Haha, well, within the context of your proposed solution to that other question, I think that situation won't have an impact. If I say `v.reserve(v.size()+1)` without it throwing, `v.capacity()` must be at least 1 bigger than the previous size, which means that I can add 1 more element without reallocating.

Comment: @Steve M: agreed, my suggestion for the "follow-up" wouldn't throw in the situation in that other question. I've not really come up with anything that throws at all, let alone in that particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it kind of depends on the allocator you are using.

Apart from the allocator, the only thing you can rely on is that `push_back()` and `push_front()` are guaranteed to be noop if an exception is thrown (23.1-10). The standard definitely doesn't forbid the `push_back()` from throwing exceptions.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: depends on the allocator in what way? Are you in effect saying that `push_back` (and presumably any other function of any container) can make arbitrary calls to the allocator that might throw, even when not reallocating? I suppose possibly I should be talking about `Alloc::construct` rather than constructors of T, but I think an allocator which throws in `construct` when the relevant constructor of T would not, is violating the standard anyway. I don't care what happens in non-conforming programs :-)

Comment: @Steve Well, the standard explicitly talks about the fact that insert/push_back are noops when an exception is thrown (other than in constructor or assignment of T). On the other hand, the reallocation should only happen when the new size is greater than old capacity. It doesn't make sense to throw anything, but it is obviously allowed.

Comment: That's my thought too, it's allowed by those clauses about insert. So the only thing that could possibly forbid it, is the other 781 pages of the standard ;-) For instance, if there was some general statement about when vectors can throw. I'm certainly not expecting any general statement about containers or sequences, since `deque` and `list` have no capacity, so for them, `push_back` must always be allowed to allocate memory.

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure about this, but I think system/CPU exceptions can be mapped into C++ runtime, so if they are, this is one case when push_back can throw.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: System/CPU exceptions being mapped to C++ exceptions are a compiler specific extension to the language (so not technically part of C++). SO unless the allocator throws because it ran out of room or T throws during construction no other exceptions should be coming your way.

Comment: @Martin Well, everything is in a sense a compiler specific extension :-D The question is if it does conform to the standard or not.

Comment: As mitigation, though, it isn't possible to write code that's exception-safe under the assumption that an exception could occur literally anywhere: `std::swap<int> (int &lhs, int &rhs) { int tmp = rhs; rhs = lhs; /* what if an exception occurs here */ lhs = tmp; }`. So I'd be very cross with the compiler vendor, and I would certainly claim that my program was conforming and has the right to expect that `swap<int>` doesn't set one int equal to the other and then throw. It's another thing entirely to throw an exception where behavior is undefined (e.g. division by 0).

Comment: (note: don't tell me I'm not allowed to specialize `std::swap<int>` ;-). I just mean to illustrate that's what `std::swap<int>` actually does, and that if I wrote that code under another name I could be rightly upset when it failed)

Comment: -1 The allocator is called during the `reserve(1)`, and is not called during the `push_back()` (as a result of calling reserve()) so a throwing allocator doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Sjoerd: The allocator's `allocate` function is called during `reserve`.  But its `construct` function is called during `push_back`.