# push_back Non-Pointer Element to Vector in One Line

Tags: c++, vector

It is possible to `push_back` `vector` elements in one line when it contains pointers:

```
vector<SomeClass*> v;
v.push_back(new SomeClass(initVar1));
v.push_back(new SomeClass(initVar2));
v.push_back(new SomeClass(initVar3));
```

Is there a way to do one-line `push_back`s like this with non-pointer variables (which are necessarily copies of other variables)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185350/is-it-safe-to-push-back-dynamically-allocated-object-to-vector

Comment: Looks like that requires C++11. Is there a way to do it with C++TR1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they have public copy constructors, of course:

```
v.push_back(SomeClass(initVar));
```

Note that `push_back` creates a copy anyway, so it seems pointless to me.  In C++11 the object will be move constructed if possible.

Also, save yourself a headache and use `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of raw pointers for your vector elements.  Using raw pointers in that way completely disables the vector's ability to manage memory for you, defeating half the purpose of using it to begin with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. You may want to edit your example to say `initVar1` because `some_instance` made me think you were talking about a copy constructor on a current instance. Which would require me to instantiate that instance and defeat the entire purpose of trying to do it in one line.

Comment: Does unique_ptr work with polymorphism? E.g. `unique_ptr<Base> b = new Derived()`?

Comment: @ChrisRedford: Yes, it follows the rules of C++.  You can pass in a pointer to a child class like you would be able to in any other situation; `std::unique_ptr<Base> b(new Derived());`