# Destructing the Vector contents in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `std::vector` of `Element*`. When will the destructor be called.
How is it different if it is a vector of `Element`

```
std::vector<Element*> vect;
..

struct Element
{
    Record *elm;        

    Element(Record *rec)
    {
        elm = new Record();
        //...copy from rec
    }
    ~Element()
    {
        delete elm;
    }
};
```

I am using the vector as follows:

```
Element *copyElm = new Element(record);
vect.push_back(copyElm);
```

In the above code, how can I ensure there's no leak.

Comment: this is really bad design.  as soon as you make a copy, the pointer will be deleted causing major headache.

Comment: @aaa Indeed. *Effective C++* gives a warning: `‘struct Element’ has pointer data members but does not override ‘Element(const Element&)’ or ‘operator=(const Element&)’`

Comment: agree with aaa, if you happen to put Element in some other container you can get lots of funny errors depending on whether the container copies internally.

Comment: @ajay: There is no leak in the above code as you are not creating any objects! show us how you are filling the vector.

Comment: @jleedev: "Effective C++ gives a warning"?  Isn't that a book?  If not, what is it and where can I get it? :)

Comment: see this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does std::list::remove method call destructor of each removed element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260464/does-stdlistremove-method-call-destructor-of-each-removed-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` will call release the memory of the object it is holding (i.e. pointers) but will not release the memory of the object it is *pointing to*.  You need to release the memory of the `Element` object yourself. If it was a `vector<Element>` then whenever you do a `push_back` a *copy* of the element is inserted into the vector. `vector` guarntess that it will release the memory allocated to this *copied object*. But be aware with the current definition of `Element` you will get a seg fault as you have not defined the copy ctor and assignment operator.

**EDIT**
If you for some reason don't want to use smart pointers, then only option is to write a `release` function which goes through the entire vector and calls the `delete` on the stored pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a reference-counting pointer-wrapper class in your array, and the items will automatically get deleted whenever there are no more references to them.  One such class is `boost::shared_ptr`.  You will also find it in some compiler's shipping C++ libraries because it is being added to a future version of C++.

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Element> > vect;
```

These classes wrap `operator ->`, etc, so you can use them in most of the same ways that you'd used a normal pointer.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you free the `class Element` instance yourself.  The vector will free the vector elements (the pointers), but not the `class Element` objects pointed to.  After all, the vector has no way to know if you have other pointers to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In a vector of `Element`, the destructor is called a *lot*.  Whenever a node is assigned, the vector is sized down, the vector has to move in memory, or the vector goes out of scope/is destroyed, destructors are called on the elements before they are changed/discarded.  Also, the copy constructor is called for assignment, and the default constructor is called to initialize each entry.  Sorting such a vector will involve a lot of both copying and destroying.

In a vector of `Element*` it is never called, unless you call `delete` yourself.

Take a look at Boost `shared_ptr` for a saner solution, or `unique_ptr` if you have a compiler with relatively new features.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying a pointer is always a no-op, and there are [several good reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261074/).