# std::vector Destruction and Unexpected Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vector

Consider the following example:

```
#include <vector>
class Foo {
    std::vector<int*> v;
public:
    Foo() {
        this->v.push_back(new int(23));
        this->v.push_back(new int(24));
        this->v.push_back(new int(25));
    }

    ~Foo() {
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    return 0;
}
```

When f goes out of scope in main(), f's destructor is called, which should indirectly free f.v.  According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/~vector/), the destructor of each element of the vector v should now be called.

However, when I run this program in valgrind, I find that the int*'s were not deallocated.

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does std::list::remove method call destructor of each removed element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260464/does-stdlistremove-method-call-destructor-of-each-removed-element)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::vector<T>` does indeed call the destructor of `T` when it is destroyed. Here `T` is `int *`. The destructor of `int *` does nothing. The storage for the `int *` itself is freed, but the `int`s they point to are not.

Consider:

```
int main() {
   int *x = new int(23);
   return 0;
}
```

This exhibits the same problem; when `x` goes out of scope, its destructor is indeed called, and the storage for the *pointer that is `x`* is freed, but since the destructor of a pointer is a no-op, the *pointed-to* `int` is not freed.

More to the point, `vector` doesn't know how the `int`s were allocated. They might be allocated by `new int`, but they could also point to elements inside an array allocated with `new int[200]`, or they might point to `malloc`'d data, or they might point into a `mmap`'d buffer, or they might point to struct elements, or two vectors might be pointing to the same `int`s... etc. `vector` isn't smart enough to divine what you want done with these, and so it leaves them alone (additionally, giving `vector` logic to delete pointed-to elements would break vectors of non-pointer elements such as `std::vector<int>`, as you can't `delete` an `int`!)

You need to either use a `std::vector<int>`, or use a smart pointer in conjunction with it, eg `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int> >`. Note that using smart pointers may add overhead; with C++0x you should be able to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` in conjunction with `std::move` to avoid this overhead. Boost also has [pointer vectors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) that free the pointed-to elements as you expected as well.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question.  The memory pointed to by the int* is not freed, though the pointer itself is.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> The destructor of each element of the vector `v` should now be called

Yes:  the `int*` objects stored in the vector are destroyed (which is effectively a no-op).  The objects pointed to by the pointers in the container are not destroyed.

Consider the following, equally valid program:

```
{
    int x;
    std::vector<int*> v;
    v.push_back(&x);
}   // x cannot be delete'd because it isn't dynamically allocated.
```

You should use a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` so that you don't have to worry about the memory management (do not use `std::auto_ptr`; it is incompatible with the Standard Library containers because it isn't really copyable).  If you don't use a smart pointer then you need to destroy the dynamically objects yourself; doing this correctly is rather difficult.

Comment: Note that `unique_ptr` can only be used in STL containers if you're using C++0x, and use `std::move` when inserting items.

Answer (score 2):

Each element of your vector is an `int *`.  When an `int *` is destroyed, the language does not automatically call `delete` on it.  In other words, it's the pointer being destroyed, not the pointee.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `new` keyword, the integers are being allocated on the heap rather than the stack. In other words, they are being allocated dynamically. In other words, you need to clean up after it.

The "destructor" for a pointer type is to simply delete that pointer. It does not touch the data which is located at the memory address stored by the pointer. Consider the following example:

```
int a = 5;
int* i = &a;
if (true)
{
   int* j = i;
} //j goes out of scope, should *i and a be deleted? no.
```

So you will need to do this in the destructor:

```
std::vector<int*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
{
   delete *iter;
}
```