# std::vector Destruction and Unexpected Memory Leak pt 2

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vector

A few hours ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638104/stdvector-destruction-and-unexpected-memory-leak).  I learned that std::vector deletes each of its elements when its destructor is called.  Consider this program (a derivative of a previous example):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
    int x;
public:
    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "~bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo {
    std::vector<Bar*> v;
public:
    Foo() {
        this->v.push_back(new Bar());
        this->v.push_back(new Bar());
        this->v.push_back(new Bar());
    }

    ~Foo() {
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;

    Bar* b = new Bar();

    // Bar::~Bar() called once
    delete b;

    // Bar::~Bar() not called three times as expected

    return 0;
}
```

b's destructor is called as expected; however, the destructors of the Bar* elements in f.v are not called.  According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/~vector/), the destructor of each element of f.v should be called.  What am I missing here?

Comment: This new example isn't at all different from your previous example:  you have a container of pointers.

Comment: Hey James: Sorry for the duplication here--I realized after the fact that I'd asked my previous question a little differently than I'd meant to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is exactly the same as the answer to the last question.  Deallocating a pointer does not call `delete` on it, so the thing it points to is not automatically destructed.

Put another way, `Bar` has a destructor, but `Bar*` does not.  So a `std::vector<Bar>` *would* invoke the destructor of each element.

Answer (score 3):

As I explained in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638104/stdvector-destruction-and-unexpected-memory-leak/6638131#6638131), destroying the pointer (`Bar *`) does not destroy the object (`Bar`). The vector destroys the pointer `Bar *` three times, but this is a no-op, the `Bar`s that are pointed to are left alone, and so you see nothing printed. If you had used a `std::vector<Bar>`, the `Bar`s would be destroyed, and you'd see the destructor called thrice.

Comment: Thanks again bdonlan.  I think I get it now: the pointers to the Bar*'s are deleted, which is *different* than the delete b in main().  In that case, the object itself is actually deleted.  What still confuses me is why the documentation says that the destructor of each element should be called when in this example, the destructor is not called.

Comment: The elements are `Bar *`s, not `Bar`s. The destructor of `Bar *` is called; the destructor of `Bar` isn't.

Comment: Ahh!!!  Yes!  That's the difference!  Bar*'s destructor is not Bar::~Bar()  Thank you for explaining this to me :-)

Comment: @rustushki: No: the pointers are not **deleted**. They are **destroyed**; there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're only deleting b in this case, also since you're not destroying Foo (and the destructor doesn't do anything anyways) it doesn't get deleted. Once the program ends it just gets rid of everything (it doesn't need to call any destructors).