# Does delete [] deallocate memory allocated by pointers to pointers

Tags: c++, memory, allocation, delete-operator

I have an array of pointers to other objects called `Comparable* array` (inside a template for a class).

I understand that `delete` deletes memory referenced by a pointer, and that `delete []` deallocates the memory assigned to each pointer in an array.

My question is if I have an array that contains pointers to other objects, how do I deallocate the memory referenced by each pointer in the array ***and*** the array itself?

Comment: -1 for not posting the code. It's very common sense that code makes question *easy* to understand without having to make any *assumption*.

Comment: +1 although posting code is often a good idea, many developers need to learn to read plain text and not only programs. In this case, plain text is self explanatory enough.

Comment: [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260464/does-stdlistremove-method-call-destructor-of-each-removed-element/4261074#4261074) and [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/)

Comment: @Serge: I've learnt to read plain text but I do that when I read post of someone who I believe knows the languages very well. When a person who comes with his doubts in C++ basics, then I really really doubt if he correctly uses the terminologies when describing his problem in *plain text*. For example, in the title he has written *pointers to pointers*, whereas in the post, he started with "an array of pointers". Is it clear enough to you?

Comment: @Nawaz The *pointers to pointers* part of the title doesn't make any sense, but IMO his question is clear enough. All 3 posted answers say the same thing, so obviously Serge and I are not the only ones who think so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> if I have an array that contains pointers to other objects, how do I deallocate the memory referenced by each pointer in the array AND the array itself?

The way you just described :) Loop through the array to delete every object and then delete the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    delete array[i];
delete[] array;
```

Comment: +1, and remembering that in the case of a pointer array of pointers-to-arrays, the loop-delete should be `delete[]` as well. In short, anything `new type[n]` needs `delete[]`. Nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

delete[] calls destructor for every object in array, if such destructor exists. For array of pointers, delete[] does not release every pointer, since pointer is plain type without destructor. You need to delete every pointer in the code.

Comment: I have "pointers don't have destructors" tattooed on my forehead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the array to deallocate the locations referenced by array indexes and need to deallocate the array itself at the end, after the loop.

Note: Assuming you have dynamically allocated using `new[]`

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

`delete[]` deletes an array of objects allocated using `new[]`, not an array of pointers.

Comment: `an array of objects`? I would say *delete[] deletes a memory pointed to by pointer, allocated using new[]*.

Comment: @Nawaz: wrong. In addition to freeing memory, `delete[]` also calls object destructors.

Comment: @Nawaz: Variables and array elements are objects in C++. As are arrays themselves :)

Comment: @Nawaz: No, `delete` and `delete[]` deal with objects, not (just) memory. When objects are deleted, their destructors need to be called. That's what `delete` and `delete[]` do.

Comment: @Serge: Correct. I wrote that incorrectly. I've to say it as: *delete[] deletes a pointer allocated using new[]*.