# Remove an item from a linked list

Tags: c++, list, struct, heap-memory

```
struct node{
    int number;
    node *next;
    };
...
node* pOne;
node* pEnd;
// create node temp 
if( pOne==NULL)            // add temp in list
    pOne = temp;
    pEnd = temp;
else { 
    pEnd->next = temp;
    pEnd = temp;
}
```

What to do if I want to delete an item from the list?
Is that adjacent elements change pointers to the following is clear.
how to remove an item from memory?

When it will not link it collects garbage collector?

Comment: C++ does not have a garbage collector. You must `delete` it.

Comment: what if you do not create a new?

Comment: If you did not create with new then you do not delete it.

Comment: When remove unnecessary objects in the program if there is no garbage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to deallocate it from memory yourself check out this other stackoverflow answer

[Does delete [] deallocate memory allocated by pointers to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397390/does-delete-deallocate-memory-allocated-by-pointers-to-pointers)