# C++ - std::list remove_if doesn't deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, list, memory-leaks, subclass, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does std::list::remove method call destructor of each removed element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260464/does-stdlistremove-method-call-destructor-of-each-removed-element)

I have a Parent class and subclassed the two children Foo and Bar. Class declarations look something like this:

```cpp
class Parent {
    public:
        virtual void action()=0;
        std::string getName() {return name;}
        Parent(std::string name): name(name) {}
        virtual ~Parent() {}
    private:
        std::string name;
}
class Foo {
    public:
        virtual void action(); //Declared somewhere else.
        Foo(int a, int b, unsigned long c, std::string name): Parent(name),a(a),b(b),c(c) {}
        virtual ~Foo() {}
    private:
        int a,b;
        unsigned long c;
}
```

Bar looks pretty much the same as Foo. I don't think the differences in their action functions and their private members will make much of a difference (it's also a bunch of ints).

I need to make a list of Parents filled with Foos and Bars. I do this to add them in and subsequently remove them:

```cpp
std::list<Parent *> pList;
pList.push_back(new Foo(1,2,3,"Thing"));
removeFromList(&pList, "Thing");
```

Where removeFromList is defined as follows:

```cpp
// Binary predicate struct, find objects with matching name.
struct NameMatch : public std::binary_function< Parent*, std::string, bool > {
     bool operator () (Parent* p, const std::string name) const {
         return (p->getName()==name);
     }
};

/* Removes a named object from the list of Foos. 
   Does nothing if a matching name can't be found. */
void removeFromList(std::list<Parent *> *pList, std::string name) {
    pList->remove_if(std::bind2nd(NameMatch(),name));
}
```

However, once I exit the program after, Valgrind will report there are memory leaks, where the lines referenced by main.cpp are the push_back operations done on the list:

```
==14230== 949 (520 direct, 429 indirect) bytes in 13 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 52 of 61
==14230==    at 0x4C28B35: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==14230==    by 0x4026C8: main (main.cpp:93)
==14230== 
==14230== 5,970 (960 direct, 5,010 indirect) bytes in 30 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 60 of 61
==14230==    at 0x4C28B35: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==14230==    by 0x40296A: main (main.cpp:112)
```

Does this mean that the list's remove_if function doesn't deallocate memory, or is there an error I made somewhere else? And how would I make sure that my program won't leak memory from using these classes? A second set of eyes would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance! (Oh, just an FYI, I can't use the Boost libraries for this assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list contain pointers to objects. You are only removing the pointer but not deallocating the memory it points to (destroying the object). You need to call `delete` on the pointer before removing it. This means that a `list::remove_if` cannot do the job here. You need to traverse the list, delete each object that matches the criteria and call `list::erase` with the iterator.

There is no easy way out here. You need runtime-polymorphism, so you need pointers and you cannot use `boost::shared_ptr`. Maybe you can cheat and use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` ;)

Comment: "make sure that my program won't leak memory": Always use containers of smart pointers instead of containers of plain pointers.

Comment: @ysdx Now he just needs the smart pointers. Sounds like that assignment just got a lot harder.