# If I call "delete" on a pointer to a vector std::vector<Object*>*, will the elements be deleted as well?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Vector Pointers to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361139/c-vector-pointers-to-objects)
>   [Does std::list::remove method call destructor of each removed element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260464/)

If I have a std::vector defined as:

```
std::vector<Object*>* myObjects;
```

And then call:

```
delete myObjects;
```

Will the elements in myObjects then also be deleted? Is there any difference using an  std::array or any other stl container?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope. This is why `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` exist.

Comment: And you also get undefined behaviour for `delete`ing an uninitialised variable, unless this variable is global or static in which case you're fine.

Comment: I thought avoiding raw pointers is one of the benefits of using containers ... `std::vector<Object> myObjects;` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> myObjects;` would be better ;-)

Comment: Why **would** anything get deleted? C++ isn't magic. It's *magical* perhaps, but it doesn't do just stuff behind your back.

Comment: I was really just wondering about the behaviour of vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and here's why.

Consider these two cases:

```
int a, b, c;

auto stackvec = new vector<int*> { &a, &b, &c };
auto heapvec  = new vector<int*> { new int, new int, new int };

delete stackvec;
delete heapvec;
```

If calling `delete` on the `vector*`s called `delete` on the pointers they hold, then you'd be in for a heap of trouble (pun intended) because you'd be `delete`ing automatic variables with the first `delete` which yields undefined behaviour (a bad thing).

You have to manually iterate the `vector` and `delete` the pointers yourself when you know they're dynamically allocated, or better, use `std::unique_ptr` and you never need to call `delete` on anything.

Also, you probably don't need a pointer to a `vector` in the first place, but I won't judge you since I don't know your situation.

As for `std::array` and `std::vector`, you need to know the size of your `std::array` at compile time and you can't resize it at runtime, but `vector` has neither of those restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you will have memory leaks.
2. No, containers of pointers do not delete pointed objects.

   - Use Boost, it has containers of pointers which own the data.
   - `boost::ptr_vector<int>`