# Why do I need to delete pointers from vector manually?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

Why do I need to delete dynamically created items in vector, manually? Why wouldn't they get deleted or its destructor called when vector got deleted?

Normally something like this, but why needed ?

```
vector<int*> v;
for (vector<int*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) 
{ 
   delete *it; 
}
```

Comment: If you have a vector of pointers, it get rids of the pointers. Destructors are not called because pointers themselves don't have destructors.

Comment: @Ynau He is asking why the data at the pointer has to be deleted.

Comment: How is vector supposed to know that your items are "dynamically created"? You store pointers in your vector. Pointers can point anywhere. They can point to dynamic objects. They can point to static objects. They all can point to the same local object. How do you propose the vector is supposed to recognize and handle all these situations?

Comment: [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261074/252000)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you store raw pointers in your vector. These pointers are just pointers. They can point anywhere. They can point to local objects, which cannot be deleted by `delete`. And even if they point to dynamically created objects, it doesn't necessarily mean that the user wants them to die with the vector. How is the vector supposed to know all this?

It is a matter of object ownership. Whoever owns the object is responsible for its proper and timely deletion. Ordinary raw pointers do not express ownership. That is why vector can't make any assumptions about whether the objects need to be deleted or not. If you want to tell the vector that it owns its dynamic objects, use corresponding smart pointers.

Secondly, note that your deletion technique is not necessarily safe in the general case. Some standard containers assume that the data you store in them is always valid. When you do `delete` on each vector element, the data in the vector becomes "invalidated" (pointers become indeterminate). This is OK with a vector. But doing something like this in a "smarter" container, like `std::map` or `std::unordered_set` for example, can and will lead to problems. Even if you destroy the container itself immediately afterwards, it is perfectly possible that the container's destruction algorithm might need to analyze (compare, hash etc.) the values of individual elements. And you just killed them all with your cycle.

Smart pointers naturally resolve this matter. But if you have to use a manual `delete` for raw pointers stored in a standard container, a better sequence of steps would be this

1. Retrieve the value of the element at `i` and store it in pointer `p`
2. Erase the element at `i` from the container
3. Do `delete p`

In the end you end up with an empty container and `delete`d data. Again, your approach will work for simple sequences, like `std::vector` or `std::list`, but don't do this with ordered or hashed ones.

Comment: Great answer, and great point about the danger of deleting elements prematurely in `std::map` et al.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with deleting elements in `std::map`. Deleting a pointer does not change its value, right?

Comment: @rafak: When you have an `std::map` that stores pointers, most of the time you'd use a comparison function that compares *pointed objects*, not the pointers themselves. But you already destroyed the pointed objects. So, if after that moment the map decides to do a comparison for some reason, it will fail. It really depends on implementation. `std::map` implementations I saw don't do this. But `hash_map` in GCC implementation does: it will crash in the destructor if you pre-delete the pointed objects like that.

Comment: @AndreyT: ok thanks for the precision. I thought you were referring to the unspecifiedness of comparing pointers pointing to objects not in the same array.

Answer (score 6):

Because the language has no way of knowing whether you need them to remain alive when you're done. What if you inserted some pointers to stack objects or something like that? Boom.

This, however, can be remedied by using a smart pointer, which *will* implement an appropriate policy as to automatic destruction. `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are the most common and useful.

Answer (score 3):

The destructor is not called because the pointer does not own the object to which it points.

In C++11, a `std::unique_ptr<T>` does indeed own the object to which it points.  In this case, the destructor is called when the pointer is released, which is probably the behavior you want.  (If you don't have a C++11 compiler but have a reasonably recent pre-C++11 compiler, `unique_ptr` is still available as part of TR1.)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `vector` was just made to delete its memory only. Pointers do not have deconstructors. And in C++, there is no garbage collection or logic to see that it is pointers and recursive delete it.

If you would like to attend the next ISO meeting and propose that, be my guest, but for me, I just put it in an `inline` function:

```
template<class T>
public static inline void deleteVectorPointer(std::vector<T*> v)
{
    for (vector<T*>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
    {
        delete *i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` will do it, no cleanup functions required.

Comment: C++11 doesn't think that's nasty :D

Comment: And there are plenty of implementations even prior to 11 which could accept `>>`.

Comment: It's only in C++11 that it was standard.