# Which way to delete pointer: delete/delete[]/free?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am implementing standart template tree structure, and I came across small problem.

Idea that each node will hold pointer to some data. Later in order to delete element correctly I need to know if its a single pointer or pointer to an array.

Inside of my `tree->ReleaseMemory()` method I have this code:

```
if (node->_data != NULL)    {

        switch (_destructionMethod){

        case  tree_delete:
            delete  node->_data; break;
        case  tree_deleteList:
            delete [] node->_data; break;
        case  tree_free:
            free(node->_data); break;

    }


}
```

where `_destructionMethod` has been set during initialisation of the node. 
Is there any way I can choose correct destructor without predefining it in special variable for it during initialisation ?

Thanks!

Comment: I thinkg this is a good time for me to figure out how to work with smart pointers, optionally I will come back to object wrapping. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this at all.  Use a smart pointer, like `shared_ptr` from C++0x or Boost or if that is not an option, `auto_ptr` from C++.  If you could have more than one object, consider using `std::vector`.

Manual resource management is messy and difficult to get right.

Comment: While this might be possible it might still be valid to use raw pointer/data depending on the situation. But if so - i dont think one should implement a Release unless you handle the allocation from the beginning.

Comment: And note the existence of `boost::checked_array_deleter` and `std::default_delete<T[]>` in C++0x

Comment: And avoid using std::auto_ptr<> with STL containers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-stl-containers

Answer (score 4):

First basic:

`delete` is used when you allocate memory with `new`:

```
int *p = new int;
int *a = new int[10];
//...
delete p; 
delete []a; //note the difference!
```

`free` is used when you allocate memory with `malloc`:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
//...
free(p);
free(a); //no difference!
```

---

Now your problem:

> Is there any way I can choose correct destructor without predefining it in special variable for it during initialisation

Consider [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). That means, write `allocator` that will encapsulate allocation and deallocation in a class and use that consistently in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the questioner knows this, since he sets `_destructionMethod` at initialization. I rather think the question is looking to avoid the need for this stored value, it is not asking which value to store.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no portable way to find out what allocator a particular pointer originally came from.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to interrogate a pointer to find out how it was allocated, but a common idiom is to give the allocated object itself responsibility for its own destruction.  It looks like your object types are not all class types, though, so you would need to wrap them in order to do this.  For example:

```
class destroyable_node
{
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class object_node : public destroyable_node
{
private:
    T * value_;

public:
    // Presumes T is copy-constructable.
    object_node(T value) : value_( new T(value) ) {}

    operator T&() {return value_;}
    operator T const &() const {return value_;}

    void destroy() {delete value_;}
};

template<typename T> class array_node : public destroyable_node
{
private:
    T * value_;

public:
    array_node(T[] value)
        : value_( new T[ sizeof(value)/sizeof(T) ] )
    {
        std::copy(value, value + sizeof(value)/sizeof(T), value_);
    }

    operator T*() {return value_;}
    operator T const *() const {return value_;}

    void destroy() {delete[] value_;}
};
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better design is to implement an abstract interface used by your container with three concrete subclasses that know what kind of thing they hold pointers to. Your container would simply call a destroy() method in the base class and let the derived classes worry about calling the correct destructor.