# c++ Linked List - Insert Object

Tags: c++, list, object, insert, abstract

I have a generic linked list that works with various types of data including objects and pointers to objects, etc, but i'm having trouble working with the list when I insert objects from a class that is derived from an **abstract class**.

I have an abstract class called vehicle and 2 classes that are carr and truck and I can do something like this:

```
list<vehicle> lv;

vehicle * v1;
vehicle * v2;

v1 = new carr;
v2 = new truck;

cin >> *v1 >> *v2;

//But when I try to insert in the list

lv.insertEnd(*v1);
```

I have the error:

**cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'vehicle'**

And the compiler show that the error is in the insertEnd method of my linked list code in the part where I write:

```
newNode->item = new Item;
```

This a part of a project where I need to have a list of vehicles and the vehicles can be carrs, trucks, etc. I have the group of vehicles implemented with pointers to pointers but i'm trying to do this with a list of vehicles.

Can you help me?

EDIT:
The item is in my linked list, i'll show my insertEnd method:

```
template <class Item>
void list<Item>::insertEnd(const Item& item)
{
    node<Item> *newNode= new node<Item>;

    newNode->item = new Item;
    *(newNode->item) = item;
    newNode->next = 0;

    if(head == 0)
    {
       head = newNode;
       tail = newNode;
        _size++;
    }
    else
    {
        novoNo->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
         _size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to insert `vehicle` instances into a container. But it's abstract. Recall that containers own their elements and thus copy their inputs. Read about slicing.

Comment: Are you trying to make a list of pointers or a list of objects? If `insertEnd` takes a `vehicle`, then it cannot take a `carr` or a `truck`, but only an instance of a `vehicle`. (Creating polymorphic collections is, unfortunately, quite irritating in C++. For one thing, there's no easy way to make a duplicate of an object given a reference or pointer to it.)

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to store an item by value in your linked list. Using items by value breaks polymorphism: only pointers or references are polymorphic.

The reason this is the error you see is that you are dereferencing your pointer here: `lv.insertEnd(*v1)`. Passing in a value this way will cause C++ to use the *copy constructor for the type specified in `insertEnd`* to make the object inside of your `insertEnd` function (check your code: the type of the parameter to `insertEnd` is surely the type specified in your template - which is `vehicle` here). By passing by value, you are telling your code to copy the whole of `v1` into a new object inside of `insertEnd`. This falls apart, because `vehicle` is an abstract class: its copy constructor cannot be used to make a fully functional object, because it's abstract.

This sort of shadows what's really going on here: you can't pass around objects by value and expect them to be polymorphic. If you don't see this error, what will likely happen is that you will likely [slice your object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), which can be even worse to debug. Do what @billz recommends and use a smart pointer.

EDIT: after seeing your addition of your insertEnd code, where you are passing by reference, there is an addendum: the compiler is *not* going to call the copy constructor in `insertEnd`. Instead, you likely see the error on this line: `newNode->item = new Item`. Here you can see where you are trying to instantiate the abstract class. Replace the word '`Item`' with '`vehicle`' - that's what you're doing with your template - and you can see it very clearly.

In any case, passing-by-reference to a dereferenced pointer is a very painful and error-prone thing indeed. It's way too easy to introduce errors: if you `delete` v1 anywhere in your code, like a good programmer does (great ones use auto pointers), you are likely to leave your reference dangling: pointing to a space in memory that someday - like when someone important is running your code - may be filled with garbage without your reference knowing it. This be the way to madness, my friend.

This is exactly why smart pointers are a C++ programmer's best friend: once you *understand* what they're doing, you can all but ignore this sort of mess and just pass them around *by value* freely. Their lifecycle contract is very well defined, they clean up after themselves, they are exception safe. As long as you don't set up reference cycles - which is far less problematic in everyday usage than passing a dereferenced pointer by reference - or [try to use auto_ptr in a standard container PLEASE READ THIS LINK AND UNDERSTAND IT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers), you've vastly reduced your memory problems.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use pointer in this case, the better way is to use smart pointer.

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<vehicle> > lv;
```

In your `list<vehicle> lv;`, `lv` only contains `vehicle` type object, `lv.insertEnd(*v1);` will **slice** your object to vehicle type which is not allow as vehicle is abstract class.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this.If I cannot do this that's not a big problem, I have this implemented with pointers to pointers and it's working, the only inconvenient is that I have to make resizes.

Answer (score 1):

since one cannot instantiate an object of abstract types, it failed to construct the object for insertion.

Also, the copy construction semantics of stl does not support polymorphic use. a "vehicle" list should only contain vehicle objects, not car objects.

You have to use container of pointers.