# Access children member of base list

Tags: c++, list, class

Is it posible to have a `std::list` of a base classes, put into it subclasses of few types, and access the children class members iterating?

Comment: You should be able to cast it to the correct type, so sure. What have you tried and why did that fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your element types are *polymorphic*, then **yes**.

The only catch is that you need to store pointers to those polymorphic objects, because containers *own* their elements and if you were to try to add a `Base` into your list, it would be copied and *sliced*, losing all the context of its more derived nature. If it's an abstract class (as it should be), then the code won't even compile.

I advise against raw pointers, so this is what we get:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
   virtual ~Base() {}
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
   void foo() { std::cout << "Lol!\n"; }
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
   void foo() { std::cout << "Haha!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> list_type;

   list_type l;
   l.emplace_back(new Derived1());
   l.emplace_back(new Derived2());
   l.emplace_back(new Derived2());
   l.emplace_back(new Derived1());

   for (auto& x : l)
      x->foo();      // <-- this is a VIRTUAL function call!
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/t7z7Gs):

> Lol!
>   Haha!
>   Haha!
>   Lol!

Yeah, it's a little verbose, but you can tidy that up with wrapper functions and whatnot.

Comment: You could reduce the verbosity with `l.emplace_back(new Derived1)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible - but make sure to store *pointers* instead of values to avoid the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct DerivedA : Base {
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "DerivedA::f\n"; }
};

struct DerivedB : Base {
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "DerivedB::f\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::list<Base *> l;
  l.push_back( new DerivedA );
  l.push_back( new DerivedB );

  for ( std::list<Base *>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it ) {
    (*it)->f();
  }
}
```

This prints

```
DerivedA::f
DerivedB::f
```

Instead of storing raw pointers it would be better to use some sort of smart pointer which takes care of calling `delete` as appropriate. C++11 features various smart pointers, make sure to [not use std::auto_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers) though!

Comment: Bah, you beat me to it because I got hung up on getting the C++11 mess right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `Derived` to `std::list<Base>` because of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), But you may do it with pointers (or better [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)).

```
std::list<Base*> l;
l.push_back(new Derived); // don't forget to delete it!!
```

you can call `(*l.begin())->method_that_present_in_base()`. If this method is virtual, method of the derived will be called.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Animal {
    virtual void say() {
        std::cout <<"I'm generic animal\n";
    }

    virtual ~Animal(){}
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
    virtual void say() {
        std::cout << "Meow\n";
    }
    virtual ~Cat(){}
};

int main() {
    std::list<Animal*> l;
    l.push_back(new Animal);
    l.push_back(new Cat);
    for(Animal* ptr: l) {
        ptr->say();
    }
    for(Animal* ptr: l) {
        delete ptr; //not needed if you use smart pointers.
    }
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/FxxvCw)

> I'm generic animal
>   Meow