# Can I create an array of auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, auto-ptr

I have a base class, which is inherited by multiple derived classes. i want to create array of autopointer of baseClass pointer. when i initialise those autopointer i get some compile time error, then i tried to do like that way

```
std::auto_ptr<base>pbase[3];

std::auto_ptr<base> b1(new derived1());
std::auto_ptr<base> b2(new derived2());
std::suto_ptr<base> b3(new derived3());

pbase[0] = b1;
pbase[1] = b2;
pbase[2] = b3;
```

it works fine, i fixed the memory leak issue, while i m one windows, i don't use valgrind, i use boost framework for leaks.

for compile error:

```
class A{
 public:
  std::auto_ptr<base>pbase[2];
}
```

in A.cpp file

```
A::A():pbase[0](new derived1()), pbase[1](new derived2()){
}
```

i got error `C2059:syntax error : '['`

Comment: Please post the error message, too.

Comment: do you have virtual destructors? Additionally, please use unique_ptr & shared_ptr instead of the auto_ptr. Think about using a std::vector to store your pointers.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated because of its weird copying behavior. Consider switching to `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Not quite the same question, so not voting to close as duplicate, but [this has useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111478/1171191).

Comment: One more thing; I guess it's just a typo, but you are accessing `pbase[3]` which invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Please try to provide an [SCCE](http://sscce.org) so we have a complete overview of the problem. ["Finding the smallest possible program that shows the problem is enough to eliminate huge numbers of possible explanations."](https://twitter.com/jcoglan/statuses/370275775129206784)

Comment: Have you tried to search for "array of auto_ptr"?

Comment: Spill the beans, what is " some compile time error"?

Comment: i have fixed the memory leak issue, it's some stupidity from my side, while i have updated the compile time error in the question.

Answer (score 7):

`std::auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++11 and should not be used because of its weird copying behavior:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> a(new int(1));
std::auto_ptr<int> b = a; // invalidates a!
```

What it tried to achieve is now solved cleanly by `std::unique_ptr`. Before the introduction of move semantics and rvalue references this was not possible.

However, this does not seem to be the problem here. From your example it is possible that you are leaking memory because you invoke undefined behavior:

```
pbase[3] = b3; // pbase is std::auto_ptr<base>[3]
               // pbase[0] - pbase[2] are valid indexes
```

In fact, when [I fix that problem](http://ideone.com/Auwsl7) and run `valgrind --leak-check=full ./auto_ptr_app` on the result, it tells me that no leak is possible.

Comment: A typical example of undefined behavior then, if you invoke undefined behavior you *may* have a memory leak... or pretty much anything else !

Comment: @MatthieuM. Exactly. This is the reason why I chose the wording *it is possible* - anything is.

Comment: @user1808932 So the index out of bounds was not causing your problem? Besides that I could only think of strange problems with polymorphism or something completely different, both which is not evident from your example

Comment: i have fixed the leak issue, it's my stupidity, while i have updated the compile time error one.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run two valgrind tests on the following pieces of code:

First run:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){}
    virtual ~Foo(){}
};

class Bar: public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(){}
    virtual ~Bar(){}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   std::auto_ptr<Foo>arr[3];

   std::auto_ptr<Foo> one(new Bar());
   std::auto_ptr<Foo> two(new Bar());
   std::auto_ptr<Foo> three(new Bar());

   arr[0] = one;
   arr[1] = two;
   arr[2] = three;
   return 0;
}
```

Second run:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){}
    virtual ~Foo(){}
};

class Bar: public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(){}
    virtual ~Bar(){}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   std::auto_ptr<Foo> one(new Bar());
   return 0;
}
```

While Valgrind indeed shows possible memory leaks in both cases, the warnings it displays are **exactly** the same (same number of warnings, same text of warnings, same stack) for both of them, pointing somewhere outside of my code to linux .so files. Thus, we can assume that the way you use the array of `auto_ptr` is fine. However, as it is stated in comments, since C++0x (which is the current C++ standard), `auto_ptr` is considered deprecated because of it's weird copy behaviour (you can find more info, for example, [in this article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=400)). It is advised to use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Now, if you are having some extra memory leaks in your code, then most likely it happens because of your own classes. Unfortunately, you haven't included them into the question, so we can't tell. In such a case, you should check your classes' constructors and destructors for memory leaks, or at least show us your classes. Another cause may be the typo in the array index that you have in the code (`pbase[3]`, which is out of bonds).

Comment: there is no leak, i have fixed that issue, it's my fault. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably not with `auto_ptr`, although that is deprecated and you should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead (if your compiler doesn't support C++11, use `boost::shared_ptr`). It seems like the leak is within your class implementation. Check if `base` has virtual destructor, because you need that if you want to use the class polymorphically. Also check for any members of base and derived classes and delete everything you allocated.