# Is it recomended to use shared_ptr as a map value?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have this two maps in a class:  (Map is a class I have built almost like the `std::map` but with only a one-directional iterator.)

```
Map<Id,shared_ptr<Fan>> fans;

Map<int,shared_ptr<FanBookPost>> posts;
```

I have a lot of memory leak and I understand its because of a broken use of `shared_ptr`
can I change it to another type of pointer that I don't have to free its location manually?
I don't need to point at one element by two pointers.

Some code from my project:

```
void FanBookServer::connect(shared_ptr<Fan> fan) {
    if(fan==NULL) {
        throw MtmBadParams();
    }
    fan->status=connected;
    fans.insert(fan->id, fan);
}
```

Comment: Maybe show us your Map class, I have not heard shared_ptr can leak memory

Comment: No issues at all regarding `std::map<>`. *Your* `Map` class on the other hand, is anyone's guess.

Comment: @marcin_j Circular references maybe? If one doesn't know how to use `weak_ptr` that could be an issue in some data structures.

Comment: `of a broken use of shared_ptr `... Any chance you're confusing `shared_ptr` with `auto_ptr`? http://stackoverflow.com/q/111478/21567

Comment: its my first time to use shared_ptr... (not auto_ptr...)
any info about it I need to know?