# can we use std::auto_ptr<> with standard containers? Yes , but using move semantics

Tags: c++

My assumption was that `std::auto_ptr` can not be used in standard containers ( [Why is it wrong to use std::auto_ptr<> with standard containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers)
), 
giving the compiler error because of only copy semantics was supported before C++11, but I think we can use `auto_ptr` same as `std::unique_ptr` in the container,  if we use move semantics with out any issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  auto_ptr<int> a1(new int(1));
  auto_ptr<int> a2(new int(2));
  auto_ptr<int> a3(new int(3));
  auto_ptr<int> a4(new int(4));

  vector<auto_ptr<int>> v1;
  v1.push_back(std::move(a1));
  v1.push_back(std::move(a2));
  v1.push_back(std::move(a3));
  v1.push_back(std::move(a4));

  for(auto it: v1)
    cout <<*it <<" ";
}
```

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated and has major issues. Use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: *Even if you make some indirection layer to make it available with the standard containers*, `auto_ptr` is **removed** since C++17. So it won't even compile with the modern compilers.

Comment: You need to use `v1` a bit more. Also what is your question?